# update 25 % of total rows returned by a select query

Tags: mysql, sql-update, logic, limit

I have to insert data into a table with columns ( col 1, col2, col 3) .

I have a select query to select the data to be inserted in this table.

```
Select A.id, b.id , '1' 
from table a 
inner join table b on a.id=b.id
where a.col= 'somevalue'and b.col ='othervalue'  ...
```

If you notice the third column in the select statment i have a hard coded value '1'. The current requirement is to set only the 25 % of the total rows with '1' and rest 75 %  with '0'. Now the difficult part is we cant be sure how many rows the select statement will come up with.
We can also use an update statement to update the 25 % rows with 1 and rest keep it as '0' but the limit fucntion will not accept any user defined variable.

Can anyone suggest something on this ?

I am using MYSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert the data into the table, keep a row number, and use modulo arithmetic:

```
insert into . . .
    select a_id, b_id, (mod(rn, 4) = 0) as flag
    from (Select A.id as a_id, b.id as b_id , (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
          from table a inner join
               table b
               on a.id = b.id cross join
               (select @rn := 0) vars
          where a.col = 'somevalue' and b.col = 'othervalue'  ...
         ) i;
```

One nice feature of taking every fourth row is that this works well, even if the data is somehow ordered because of the `join`.

Comment: Hi, this thing works great . Actually even that 25 % is a parameter. Which will have values 25 %, 50 % and 100 % . MOD works for all of these .

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the total number of rows. Then use a user-defined variable to get the row number in the output, and compare it to 25% of the total.

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, IF(@counter < pct25, '1', '0'), @counter := @counter + 1
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*)/25 AS pct25
      FROM table1 a
      JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id) AS x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @counter := 0) AS var
```

Comment: The idea seemed to be good but my query already has 10 inner joins and couple of exists and not exists . Putting this whole query into subquery will make it very costly.

Comment: Save the results of the expensive query in a temporary table, then query that.

Comment: You could also use an `auto_increment` field in the temporary table, so you don't need to use the user variable for the counter.